# changing label size and position runtime tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using `customCell` in `UITableView` my cell has diffrent `UILabel` in customCell

I want to change the size of the labels according the text to be displayed so that no text truncates  and the positions of the labels below the label which size has changed so that no label overlap each other.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're subclassing `UITableViewCell` you can layout your custom labels in `layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    myCustomLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 5, 5, self.bounds.width - 5, 40 );
    myOtherCustomLabel.frame = CGRectMake( CGRectGetMinX( myCustomLabel.frame ), CGRectGetMaxY( myCustomLabel.frame ), myCustomLabel.frame.size.width, 30 );
}
```

To calculate the size needed for text, use `sizeWithFont:`

```
CGSize textSize = [textString sizeWithFont:labelFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake( widthOfCell, CGFLOAT_MAX ) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```